# Solar powered TP4056 Lipo Charger burning

Tags: solar-cell, lipo

My project is to build a porch light which will run on a 3.7V Lipo battery, which is charged via 5V solar panel during the day. It has a PIR sensor and has a set timer to light a large LED  once a person trigers the PIR. The circuit also has a LDR so the light only turns on during the night.

I have used an ATmega328 and already built an initial version running on a 3Cell Lipo and a step down buck converter as per the pictures.

So I have done some research and decided to use a 3.7V single Cell Lipo + TP4056 as the Lipo charger and an MT3608 DC to DC converter to provide 5 volts to the Atmega and the 5V LED.

The problem is when I tried to test the design by putting very small amount of voltage with my bench power supply to the TP4056 (like the Solar panel will in the early hours of the morning) ; I keep frying the unit!. On this test, I have the 3.7V 18650 3400mAh battery connected to the battery port but the load is not connected. I also did not use any diodes on this test. 
But when I provide 5V directly there is no issues and the charging starts

1) What could be the reason for the TP4056 to burn? Is it the lipo current leaking to the unit?

2) Is there a better way to provide 5V constantly to a circuit with a lipo and a solar panel setup?

**Q U E S T I O N    ----    U P D A T E :**

Based on the feedback, Here is more detail on the problem;

As per the picture, I have connected the lipo battery without any load on the TP4056 board and used my bench power supply to power the board.
All is OK when I apply 2 Amps and 5 volts to the board and the lipo starts charging around 480mA's. But when I reduce the amp to 500mA on the bench power supply the board is fried.

This is a standard board that I purchased from e-bay and here is the DataSheet: http://www.haoyuelectronics.com/Attachment/TP4056-modules/TP4056.pdf

Is that a normal behaviour? What am I missing here?

**Q U E S T I O N    ----    U P D A T E ----  N U M B E R ----2:**

I have tested the TP4056 outside with the actual sollar cells. I connected 2 5.5V ones paralel and received around 500mA curent to the Lipo and the good news is the unit was not fried when it get dark and the solar cells did not provide enough current.
I suspect the issue may be with my bench power supply. It is a buck converter not a linear one but I still dont understand how the TP4056 fries as I crank down the amps. 
Any ideas ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the schematics? The site has a schematic editor.

Comment: Projects involving battery charging are generally not a good place to start, they tend to be extremely complex with many hard to understand failure modes.  Given you have failed to provide the actual design of your circuit, you are only calling for wild speculation, while this site is only for questions supported by full detail.  Additionally, neither an ATmega nor an LED really need five volts, so the boost converter is likely unnecessary and power wasting complication.

Comment: What’s the open circuit voltage and short circuit current of the solar panel?

Comment: Thanks for the comments Chris. Will try to be more specific going forward.

Comment: Lior -  the schematics is on this link: but the issue is when I try to run the TP4056 with low voltage from the bench power supply the unit is heating and burning. Which is not on this schematic https://easyeda.com/editor#id=91f0c7c9907e4b3e9295086996005a31

Comment: Winny - I read around 5.5 Volts when it is full sun exposure on the panel. Not sure how to test the short circuit current?

Comment: what is the power supply voltage when current limiting is set to 500 mA?

Comment: jsotola - Voltage is not changed. Still 5 Volts. But as I dial down the amps the led on TP4056 board goes out and and the board fries!

Comment: @AlperKayar you mentioned that the voltage remains constant, even when you reduce current. This is not possible. If you reduce current, the voltage will change because \$V=IR\$ and \$R\$ is pretty much constant here. 

I'm guessing that your power supply is reducing the voltage and not updating the voltage on the display. This causes the undervoltage protection to kick in on the TP4056 and it stops operating. You should first make sure that Constant current mode is working on your power supply and then update the question.

Comment: TP4056 Vin is 5.5V abs max from memory.

Comment: _" I suspect the issue may be with my bench power supply."_ - exactly which bench power supply do you have?

Comment: Its a stock PS that I bough on Ebay : 0-28V 0.01-2A DC Regulated Power Supply DIY Kit For Constant-current Source R4C6